# Howto limit widt of search input when using Google Custom search

Tags: google-custom-search

I would like to regulate the search form with the button and input box to not take the hole width of the page.

I am able to regulate the input box it self by using with: 80%; but not the hole form.

Greatly appreciate if anyone can give me a tip :)

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can put this form into some div and specify width property of this div. If form takes all page then if this form was inside the div you made form automatically adjust width depending of this div.

There is some good documentation about this. Check this link https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

I think this "Compose different layout options using Custom Search Elements" is that you need.